# Stability of the fixed point at the bifurcation point; is there a proof of this method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, bifurcation

In my nonlinear dynamics lecture, it has been stated that:

---

In general, close to a bifurcation, we expand $f(x,\nu)$ up to linear in $\nu-\nu_c$ and up to first non-zero term in $x-x_*$,
$\newcommand{\pd}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}$
\begin{multline}
\dot x=\underbrace{f(x_*,\nu_c)}_{=0}+\underbrace{\pd{f}{x}\big|_{...}(x-x_*)}_{=0}+\pd{f}{\nu}\big|_{...}(\nu-\nu_c)
\\
+\pd{^2f}{x\partial\nu}\big|_{...}(x-x_*)(\nu-\nu_c)
+\frac12\pd{^2f}{x^2}\big|_{...}(x-x_*)^2
+\frac12\pd{^2f}{\nu^2}\big|_{...}(\nu-\nu_c)^2
\\
+\frac16\pd{^3f}{x^3}\big|_{...}(x-x_*)^3+\dots
\end{multline}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9CDs.png)
\begin{array}{cc|ccl}
\pd{f}{\nu}&\pd{^2f}{x\partial\nu} & \pd{^2f}{x^2} & \pd{^3f}{x^3} & \\
\hline
\ne 0&&\ne 0&&\begin{aligned}
\dot x &= a(\nu-\nu_c)+b(x-x_*)^2\\
\dot x &= \nu-x^2\\
&\text{saddle-node}
\end{aligned}\\
\hline
=0&\ne 0&\ne 0&&
\begin{aligned}
\dot x &= a(\nu-\nu_c)(x-x_*)+b(x-x_*)^2\\
\dot x &= \nu x-x^2\\
&\text{transcritical}
\end{aligned}\\
\hline
=0&\ne 0&=0&\ne 0&
\begin{aligned}
\dot x &= a(\nu-\nu_c)(x-x_*)+b(x-x_*)^3\\
\dot x &= \nu x-x^3\\
&\text{pitchfork}
\end{aligned}\\
\end{array}

---

For a given system of the form $$\dot x = f(x, \nu),$$ where $\nu$ is the bifurcation parameter, at a bifurcation point, the stability of the fixed point is mainly determined by highest order nonzero terms in the Taylor series expansion of $f$ wrt $x$ and $\nu$.

However, is there a proof of this fact?

Intuitively, the higher-order terms should have less effect, but this doesn't necessarily mean that they will not effect the resulting stability. After all, we will be ignoring *infinitely* any terms.

Comment: You mean the lowest-order terms, or lowest-degree terms. The non-linear coordinate transformation that you ask about is the basis for bifurcation and catastrophe theory, their existence theorems should be found in all relevant text books.

Comment: @LutzLehmann can you suggest one then, if that is some common? Because I've checked and couldn't find.